# Google Maps JS API: Gradient Polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the iOS version of the Google Maps API, there's a way of doing gradient polylines using the "spans" property.

http://www.googblogs.com/gradient-polylines-and-structured-reverse-geocoding-results-google-maps-sdk-for-ios-v1-7/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7#change_the_color_of_individual_line_segments

However, there's no mention of this option via JavaScript.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Polyline

Is there a good way to do a gradient polyline via JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems this is a limitation of SVG, we just created a ton of lines with little gradients instead.